# What is the easiest way to tweak APC SHM size per user?

Tags: php, shared-memory, apc, mod-fcgid

So I've completely finished setting up APC and I'm liking it so far. The only thing is; Memory is a bit of a constraint on my system. I know: buy more, right? Well, my host doesn't support it and I like their service so...

I'm running APC using FCGID on a cPanel/WHM server. Cache is shared between visits on a per user basis because I use FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1 in php.conf.

By default, APC is initialized when APC is started, so all user accounts have ONE (MaxProcesses) unique and personal share of SHM, but the SHM size is the same for all users. However, I have some sites that would really benefit from having, say, 128M of SHM whereas others could easily suffice with 16M or even 8M in some cases.

I've already been fiddling with custom fcgi loaders in /cgi-bin and the likes as described here:

http://www.brandonturner.net/blog/2009/07/fastcgi_with_php_opcode_cache/

and http://chrisgilligan.com/search/apc-shm_size-each-user/

But it would seem to me that if APC is already loaded on a per-user basis, there should be a simpler option. I can't really get per-user FCGI to work and still persist the php process.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be impossible with Mod_FCGID.
Since I can't get Mod_FastCGI to run on my server, which would make this possible, I've since switched to Mod_DSO. Everything is shared now, so it's okay.